# Cisco ASA - Unable to create "range" type of network object on 8.2

Tags: networking, cisco-asa, ip-blocking

I'm wanting to block a range of ip addresses on my Cisco ASA 5520 (8.2) using ASDM 6.4.

In the help files/cisco documentation, it says, just create a network object with a "range" type, and use that in a blocking access rule...

When I'm accessing the ASA (8.2) with ASDM 6.4, I go to config>firewall>object>network objects & groups, then click "add" to add the IP range as a "network object", I get the following 4 fields to fill out:

Name: 
IP address:
Netmask: 
Description:

That's all... In the context-sensitive help files, it says that there should be a Type drop-down to select, with "range" being one of the options, but there is no "Type" drop-down list...

If I try to create a "network object group" instead of just "network object", then I get a "Type" drop down list, but it only contains two options: network  &   host    (No "Range" option here either)

Can someone help me figure out how to block a range of IP's, using the current 8.2 version on the ASA?

Thanks for any pointers or tips!

Answer (score 2):

ASA didn't begin supporting the `object` command (and thus address ranges) until version 8.3. ASDM 6.4 supports ASA versions newer than 8.2, and the online help (and possibly even the GUI) probably reflect features available in versions newer than yours. Assuming it works at all, I would guess the ASDM implements this feature using an `object-group` instead, which doesn't support IP ranges (just hosts and subnets).

References:

- [ASA 8.3 Release Notes](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa83/release/notes/asarn83.html#wp460665) (scroll down a bit to the "Firewall Features" section)
- [Command reference for `object network` command](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa83/command/reference/no.html#wp1819044) (scroll down to "Command History" section)